# How To Find All Comments In Dynamically Generated Facebook Comment Boxes

Tags: facebook, find, comments, box

Currently I am using a bit of code from Facebook to generate comment boxes on my site. I dynamically generate a different comment box for each article on the site -- and it works! -- but the problem is that I have SO many different comment boxes pointing to so many different URLs and I did not generate the comment boxes through any central Facebook app, so I am unsure how to check the users/comments that I receive in those boxes!

Below is the code that I use to generate the comment box on each page, with the $url variable is always equal to the URL that the comment box is being displayed on:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
 (function(d, s, id)
     {
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo $url ?>" data-num-posts="12" data-width="100%"></div>
```

Is there any way to check for comments if this is how I generate my comment boxes?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#moderation